# How to make a custom WPF collection?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, collections

I'm trying to create a custom set of classes that can be added to a WPF control through XAML.

The problem I'm having is adding items to the collection. Here's what I have so far.

```
public class MyControl : Control
{
    static MyControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyControl)));
    }

    public static DependencyProperty MyCollectionProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyCollection", typeof(MyCollection), typeof(MyControl));
    public MyCollection MyCollection
    {
        get { return (MyCollection)GetValue(MyCollectionProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyCollectionProperty, value); }
    }
}

public class MyCollectionBase : DependencyObject
{
    // This class is needed for some other things...
}

[ContentProperty("Items")]
public class MyCollection : MyCollectionBase
{
    public ItemCollection Items { get; set; }
}

public class MyItem : DependencyObject { ... }
```

And the XAML.

```
<l:MyControl>
    <l:MyControl.MyCollection>
        <l:MyCollection>
            <l:MyItem />
        </l:MyCollection>
    </l:MyControl.MyCollection>
</l:MyControl>
```

The exception is:
`System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message="'MyItem' object cannot be added to 'MyCollection'. Object of type 'CollectionTest.MyItem' cannot be converted to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemCollection'.`

Does any one know how I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Could you inherit your base class from one of the DOM-centric collection classes in System.Collections.ObjectModel?  These classes (e.g. Collection, KeyedCollection, etc) are great for creating DOM style interfaces as they support overridable add/remove functions.  I know this isn't a direct response to you question, but wondered if there was some reason not to do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more googling, I found [this](http://statestreetgang.net/post/2008/07/More-on-XAML-Serialization.aspx) blog which had the same error message. Seems I need to implement IList as well.

```
public class MyCollection : MyCollectionBase,  IList
{
    // IList implementation...
}
```

Comment: This is different than your original code - it will add items to `MyCollection` itself, and not to its `Items` property.

Answer (score 1):

Did you perhaps forget to create an instance of `ItemCollection` in the constructor of `MyCollection`, and assign it to `Items` property? For XAML parser to add items, it needs an existing collection instance. It won't create a new one for you (though it will let you create one explicitly in XAML if the collection property has a setter). So:

```
[ContentProperty("Items")]
public class MyCollection : MyCollectionBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<object> Items { get; private set; }

    public MyCollection()
    {
         Items = new ObservableCollection<object>();
    }
}
```

Comment: ItemCollection has no public properties. Is there another way of creating it?

Comment: Sorry, I meant no public constructors.

Comment: Good point - looks like it's `internal`, and is really intended to only be used by `ItemsControl`. So either derive from `ItemsControl` (if it makes sense for your class), or use any other XAML-supported collection class, such as `ObservableCollection<T>`. I've updated the example accordingly.